# How to prove consistency with choice for large cardinal extensions?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, axiom-of-choice, large-cardinals

How can we know if an extension of $\sf ZF$ by some large cardinal property that results in a consistency strength beyond $0^{\#}$ is compatible with choice or not?

I mean the easiest way to know if an extension of $\sf ZF$ is compatible with choice is to construct a model of it in $L$. But if any extension goes beyond $0^{\#}$ then no model of it can be constructed in $L$, and so there is no uniform way to prove its compatibility with choice.

Is there something that takes the place of $L$ for those high kinds of extending  $\sf ZF$? Is it $\sf HOD$? Or perhaps other known models in which choice hold. Also, are there known models that can interpret partial forms of choice, like $\sf CC$ and $\sf DC$ principles at such altitudes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the territory of **inner model theory**.

The issue with $\mathsf{HOD}$ is that it's far too flexible: there's generally no easy way to argue (and indeed it's usually false) that passing to $\mathsf{HOD}$ preserves large cardinals. So the mere fact that $\mathsf{HOD}^\mathcal{M}\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ whenever $\mathcal{M}\models\mathsf{ZF}$ doesn't help us much. Instead, we need a more explicit construction. This is where **mice** and their ilk enter the picture ([Schimmerling's *The ABCs of mice*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2687795) is the closest thing I know to a readable intro to mouse theory).

However, it's also worth noting that the *definitions* of large cardinal notions often rely on choice in subtle ways. For example, it's (we hope!) consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that $\omega_1$ is measurable via the club filter. Similarly, we currently don't know whether "If a Reinhardt is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ then it's consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$" is correct (we know the conclusion is false but the hypothesis could be true). And speaking only for myself, I am not entirely sure what the "right" choice-free definition of a supercompact cardinal is in the first place! So you should absolutely not think of relative-choice-consistency as a *trivial* or *automatic* sort of result, once we climb up to the exciting levels of the large cardinal hierarchy.

That said, a good starting point is definitely the model $L[\mathcal{U}]$, the "measurable-accommodating" analogue of $L$. If memory serves, both [Jech](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-44761-X) and [Kanamori](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-88867-3) have good treatments.